# what does the term `fac` mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, primitive, factorial

What does the term `fac` mean in Haskell? I've seen it on many occasions but it appears to not have any definition of being of any type. I know it has something to do with factorials but am not quite sure what people mean when they refer to the term `fac`.

Here's an example:

```
sumFacs n = fac 0 + fac 1 + ... + fac (n-1) + fac n
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually `fac` refers to the factorial function, which can be defined as:

```
fac :: Int -> Int
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n - 1)
```

Of course, there are [many different ways to define factorial in Haskell](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html).

Comment: Shorter is `fac = product [1..n]`. Anyway, [here](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html) are other equivalent definitions.

Comment: @Alexandre C, Small typo, it should be `fac n = product [1..n]`.

Comment: or `fac = product . flip take [1..]`

Comment: or `fac = product . enumFromTo 1`

Answer (score 0):

It's the abbreviation for [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).